# Python: why does this local list variable in class method retain its value?

Tags: python-2.7, list, class, methods

I searched around and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) which gives me a lead on why this is happening -- it seems I've just come across a more complex and subtle case of it.  But it's those subtleties that have me bewildered and looking for a clearer explanation.  (I doubt it matters, but just in case:  I'm using Python 2.7.x on Windows 7.)

The starting point is this bit of code, which I distilled from a much larger and more complex app where I first encountered the problem.

```
class MyClass():
    def printStuff(self,myList=[1,2,3],myInt=4):
        print '--------------------------------'
        print 'myList at start: '+str(myList)
        print 'myInt  at start: '+str(myInt)
        doNotCare = myList.pop()
        myInt = myInt - 1
        print 'myList at end:   '+str(myList)
        print 'myInt  at end:   '+str(myInt)

testMC = MyClass()
testMC.printStuff()
testMC.printStuff()
testMC.printStuff()
```

...which generates the following output:

```
--------------------------------
myList at start: [1, 2, 3]
myInt  at start: 4
myList at end:   [1, 2]
myInt  at end:   3
--------------------------------
myList at start: [1, 2]
myInt  at start: 4
myList at end:   [1]
myInt  at end:   3
--------------------------------
myList at start: [1]
myInt  at start: 4
myList at end:   []
myInt  at end:   3
```

Now, based on the various write-ups on how defaulted parameters are handled in functions, it seems like `myInt` should exhibit the same behavior as `myList`, i.e. it should decrement to 3, 2, 1.  But obviously it doesn't.

The puzzle gets more complex if I modify the `doNotCare = myList.pop()` line, instead using a slice to update the list:

```
class MyClass():
    def printStuff(self,myList=[1,2,3],myInt=4):
        print '--------------------------------'
        print 'myList at start: '+str(myList)
        print 'myInt  at start: '+str(myInt)
        myList = myList[:-1]
        myInt = myInt - 1
        print 'myList at end:   '+str(myList)
        print 'myInt  at end:   '+str(myInt)

testMC = MyClass()
testMC.printStuff()
testMC.printStuff()
testMC.printStuff()
```

...which somehow defeats that unexpected retained value, yielding the output:

```
--------------------------------
myList at start: [1, 2, 3]
myInt  at start: 4
myList at end:   [1, 2]
myInt  at end:   3
--------------------------------
myList at start: [1, 2, 3]
myInt  at start: 4
myList at end:   [1, 2]
myInt  at end:   3
--------------------------------
myList at start: [1, 2, 3]
myInt  at start: 4
myList at end:   [1, 2]
myInt  at end:   3
```

So I suppose the first question would be, is this in fact just a more complex and subtle case of the default-parameter behavior described in the reference?  If it is, then why doesn't the behavior apply to `myInt` -- or even to `myList`, when I manipulate it with slicing instead of `pop`?

Comment: [Mutable default argument.](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike lists, numbers are immutable, so they can't be changed. References to them can be reassigned, but a 1 will always be a 1.

And splicing doesn't produce this behavior because it creates a copy of the original, whereas `pop` modifies the original list.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense of it.  So tuples wouldn't be affected either -- only lists, dictionaries, etc.

Comment: @JDM Right. Anything immutable, tuples included, are "safe". You need to be careful with mutable objects though.